# Is it possible to modify the test server configuration in each separate microservice project?

Tags: eclipse, microservices, development-environment, open-liberty

I am developing a number of microservices which will run on Open Liberty. I have set up a test server in my eclipse environment which is configured to use all the features required by all the services which I am currently working on.

Whilst this works, it seems a heavy-handed approach and it would be good to test each service in an environment which closely resembles the target server. The services can differ in the set of features they require as well as the JVM settings necessary.

Each service will run in its own docker container and the docker configuration is defined in each project.

Is there a way to better test these services without explicitly setting up a new server for each individual service?

Comment: I've seen test frameworks where the test copies in a different server.xml, then Liberty updates itself to add/remove features, usually without restarting.   But it's not self-contained in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to segment the Liberty runtime (its features) nor the jvm (for different jvm settings) for different applications running in a single Liberty instance.

You can set app specific variables and retrieve them using MP Config, but that's not the same as jvm settings and certainly not the same as trying to segment specific features of the runtime to a specific application.

However, in general when testing, I would highly recommend trying to mimic your production environment as much as possible.  Since you're planning on deploying into docker, I would do the same locally when testing, and given Liberty's lightweight, composable nature, it's unlikely that you'll hit resource issues locally when doing this (you should only enable the features on each Liberty instance that your app is using to minimize the size of that instance).  This approach is one of the big benefits/value provided by containers and Liberty.

In other words, even if you could have one Liberty instance segmented per application, I would not recommend it for your testing because, as you said, "it would be good to test each service in an environment which closely resembles the target server"